# Send push notification with flutter without FCM

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a few questions regarding the management of push notifications with Flutter.
Reading on Google, if I have not understood, it seems that FCM does not send push notifications at a particular scheduled time. Correct?
If yes, I'll explain my problem.
I am developing an application that monitors aircraft flights and I have set up a section within the app, where the user can indicate the day and time when the user wants to receive the push notification.
For example, I am monitoring flight number AZ654 and I want a push notification for every day of the week at 10:34 am
To be able to implement this type of implementation, I need to set up a backend system that displays a rest service, where I pass some parameters from the app, including the DEVICEID and the DEVICETOKEN and the type of device if Android or iPhone.
My doubts start here.
1. Is it possible to retrieve the DEVICEID and DEVICETOKEN information via Flutter?
2. The authorization window to receive push notifications that appears on IOS, appears automatically when I implement the management of push notifications with Flutter or do I necessarily have to implement an implementation on the native code of both Android and IOS?
Thank you all.
Vincenzo

Comment: You might wanna consider embedding a MQTT client in your app and a MQTT broker on the server, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 1):

Try OneSignal https://onesignal.com/ it has what you need to achieve your needs.
under the hood its somewhat FCM.

Comment: No onesignal is not free

Comment: its practically free for notifications which what you only need. https://onesignal.com/pricing . Unlimited Subcribers + Unlimited Notifications are included in the free plan.